# My C# form closes and returns the control to the previous form.

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a desktop application in C#. In the code, if have to load a new from. I have used the [dot]ShowDialog() function for the object of the form I want to load. While the new form loads and works just fine, after completion of a function call (button press), the control returns to the parent form automatically however it should have stayed on the child form. Can any one please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Care to show your code so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: It will happen when your modal form is closed. Please, add the code that runs when this button is pressed.

Answer (score 3):

I make a wild guess, but this behavior is typical when the button pressed has its property `DialogResult` set to something different than `None`.

Usually this happens when you have made a copy/paste of your button from a prexistent button like the OK or Cancel that have their property DialogResult set.